# How to auto-boot game when PS3 is started?

Tags: ps3

Is it possible to auto-boot a game when the console is started? Today, games take a lot of time to load, and I'd like to speed up the process a bit.

Is there any way to just start the game when you turn on your PS3?

Answer (score 5):

There's an [Disc Auto-Start](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/discboot.html) option under Settings > System Settings that sounds a lot like what you want, but that won't start it when you turn your PS3 on, only when you put in a disc. It used to behave like you wanted, but they changed it to the current way in update 3.0. I don't think that there's any way now.

Comment: Set Disc Auto-Start to [On] and do like Mr Smooth tell: take the disc out and put it back in.

Comment: @SilverM-A: That works, but it's almost as easy to just pick it in the menu then.

Comment: I agree! We should do the speed tests!

However, it is possible to insert the disk during the pre-load. It starts automatically when the PS3 comes out of the initializing. We are talking about seconds, then I think it is free for everyone to choose his method;)